# Facebook canvas app - blank page

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I am having a weird issue with facebook canvas application and clicking on app request notifications.

Basically if you are in the app, and someone else sends you an app request for the same app, then the notification globe will show the request. If you click on it then it just shows the message loading 'app name' and goes blank.

Works perfectly if you click on the app request while not using the app (e.g on facebook homepage).

I tried using js developer tools and it looks facebook is performing an ajax request which is not returning anything (hence blank page I suppose). The url for the ajax request is

**http://apps.facebook.com/ajax/canvas/storyboxfb_app_name=appId&_*user=userId&*_a=1**

Anyone got any ideas??

Comment: Seems as if there is a bug post regarding this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/522157731130323?browse=search_508855e01b7b92b23024420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue seems to have disappeared after I supplied an app namespace. Seems like it only occurs if you use the default app id as the namespace.

Comment: that fixed it for me too. thnx.

Comment: What do you mean with app namespace?

Comment: See here https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/851562_301533066646932_1600394797_n.png